# Displaying the contents of an Arraylist from a subclass

Tags: java

> I cannot get the results to print from the Account ArrayList created in my customer class.

```
public static void customerInteraction(Customer cust) throws Exception {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);



    int custInput;

    //write the logic here to interact with the customer and the account(s)
    System.out.println("Your customer was successfully located.");
    System.out.println("Hi "+cust.fullName());
    System.out.println("Here are your Accounts.");

    // display the Accounts in the list
    **for (int i = 0; i < cust.acctList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.printf(" %s", cust.acctList.get(i));**
    **}**
```

> I can create a customer and save the account information to the acctlist Account Arraylist

```
    Customer Class
public void addAccount(String acctType) {
        if (acctType.equalsIgnoreCase("CHECKING")) {acctList.add(new Checking(this.custId));
        } else {
            acctList.add(new Savings(this.custId));
        }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is `acctList` public?

Comment: ArrayList<Account> acctList = new ArrayList<>(); is declared in th customer class

Comment: The printout I get is Here are your Accounts.
 teller.Checking@4bd66d2f

Answer (score 0):

Use *Name I forget* as part of Java 1.6+:

Its much more readable and should help you figure out if anything else is wrong.

```
for (E element : cust.acctList) {
    // Do stuff with each element E
enter code here}
```